# Making a phone call directly from my flutter App

Tags: flutter

I wanna make a phone call directly from my flutter App. i tried using the "URL-Launcher" plugin, but it will only direct the phone number to dialer pad. can you please help me how i can call using only my app without redirecting it?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phone_direct_caller) plugin.

```dart
await FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(number);
```